# When dealing with an object's constructor that is being passed a variable number of String parameters, how do i assign each one a name?

Tags: java

So for example we could have something like:

```
public class MyConstructor
{
int integer;
String string;

public MyConstructor(int integer, String string)
{
this.integer = integer;
this.string = string;
 }
}
```

But now dealing with a variable amount of Strings being passed, I could have something (I think) like:

```
public class MyConstructor
{
int integer;
String string;

public MyConstructor(int integer, String...string)
   {
   }
}
```

But my question is, how do I assign each parameter of type String that is being passed in, a name?

If i just had (within the body of the contructor):

```
for (String s : string)
 {
  this.string = string
  }
```

I would just be overwriting my last assignment each time.

So basically, how do i declare a variable number of String variables?
Or do I do this someother way?
Thanks

Comment: You use an array or a collection, basically - that's what they're for...

Comment: Your comment was so helpful

Comment: His status has nothing to do with the helpfulness (or lack thereof) of his post..

Comment: @George instead of complaining, have you tried understanding, and applying, Jon's comment? It's absolutely correct. And if you don't know what an array is and how to use arrays, then you shouldn't be using varargs yet, but learn about arrays instead. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Then why don't you ask that then? Have you read the chapter about arrays in your Java book? Or followed and read the link I gave you? How are we supposed to know, from your question, that you don't know how to use arrays?

Comment: If I knew to use an array or collection here, I would have. The fact that this idea appears no where in my post indicates I did not think to do it this way. Now, if it so obviously the right way to go about doing this (which I believe), then it is reasonable to assume I don't know much about arrays or collections, for if I did I would have immediately recognized to use them here. So, then, telling someone to use something--of which, it is clear they don't know how to use--as Jon Skeet did, would not be a helpful answer. A helpful answer would be: "You need to use a collection in this way..."

Comment: I appreciate your answer at least, giving me a link. I'm simply frustrated with Jon Skeet's comment along with someone else comment showing me his rank...as if that has anything to do with the quality (which may infact be deemed good quality to some) of his post.

Comment: That's why Jon posted it as a **comment**, not an answer. It's a very useful hint. It tells you that you need to learn about arrays, if you haven't, and that you need to use one, if you know how. Why don't you stop complaining and start to do some research. Get used to it: being a programmer implies reading documentation every day.

Comment: Yes, I will now look up more on arrays. You are right though, it is a useful comment. I forgot there was a distinction here between comment and answer. It is a good comment, a good hint. As a formal answer,  though, I believe my points would stand.